# Range("R2").Value = ActiveCell.Address

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to use that address somehow after it pops up in cell R2?  So far I have been able to get the address of my copied cell to go in cell R2 by entering that line at the end of my macro to copy cells.  Now I want to be able to go back to that cell after it is pasted in another cell so I can clear it.

Still trying to (copy, paste special, clear copied cell) after it as been pasted elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you write the cell address into a worksheet cell at all? Store it in a variable, then you don't need to mess with worksheet cells. Post your code and explain more of what you are trying to achieve. EDIT your question to do that and post a comment to alert your followers to the changes.

Comment: Also, you can use .Select to activate a cell. From that moment ActiveCell does reference to that cell. For example `Range("A1").Select` followed by `ActiveCell.Text = "new value"`

Comment: I am trying to copy and paste special  values only and then delete the source.  Since when I use the cut fonction it also takes the format with it and it paste it to the destination cell with the formating.  I basically want something that will cut values only and paste values only.

Comment: Sub PasteAsValue()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
' here I am trying to add a line to delete the source of the pasted value if possible or a total different way of doing it (sorry I am new to vba).
   
End Sub

Comment: @LPChip  I just saw now what you wrote Yesterday.  That is pretty much the code I used..Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for.

Either of these lines added to my code worked to go back to the copied cell to clear it. Might not be the best  way of doing it but it does exactly what I wanted it to do.

```
Range(Range("R2")).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Or

```
Range([indirect("R2")]).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

So I have a Macro for copy that is used when `Ctrl+c` is pressed that copies the active cell just like a normal copy does but it also puts the address of the active cell in R2.

Then I have one for `ctrl+v` to paste values only and then go back to the copied cell and clear it.